# Reorganize List into ListBox after adding a new Item

Tags: c#, winforms

I have list  in listbox where I want to order by a field once I added item to it:

```
var lstdata = (List<EmployeeAssignationModel>)lstTechToNotified.DataSource;
lstdata.Add(new EmployeeAssignationModel()
{
    UserName = selectedItem.UserName,
    EmpGuid = selectedItem.EmpGuid,
    Name = selectedItem.Name,
    Abbreviation = selectedItem.Abbreviation
});

lstTechToNotified.DataSource = null;
lstTechToNotified.DisplayMember = "Abbreviation";
lstTechToNotified.ValueMember = "UserName";
lstTechToNotified.DataSource = lstdata;


lstTechToNotified.Refresh();
```

So I try adding `OrderBy` once item is added like:

```
var lstdata = (List<EmployeeAssignationModel>)lstTechToNotified.DataSource;
lstdata.Add(new EmployeeAssignationModel()
{
    UserName = selectedItem.UserName,
    EmpGuid = selectedItem.EmpGuid,
    Name = selectedItem.Name,
    Abbreviation = selectedItem.Abbreviation
});
lstdata.OrderBy(x => x.Abbreviation);

lstTechToNotified.DataSource = null;
lstTechToNotified.DisplayMember = "Abbreviation";
lstTechToNotified.ValueMember = "UserName";
lstTechToNotified.DataSource = lstdata;

lstTechToNotified.Refresh();
```

But it just don't update, it always send item added to bottom of the list. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OrderBy returns a new list, rather than doing the changes in place:

```
lstdata = lstdata.OrderBy(x => x.Abbreviation).ToList();
```

Try this instead.

You'll see here it returns a collection: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: OrderBy returns an `IOrderedEnumerable so `lstdata = lstdata.OrderBy(x => x.Abbreviation).ToList()`

Comment: I try but I get error: `Error CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<Models.EmployeeAssignationModel>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Models.EmployeeAssignationModel>`

Comment: add the tolist part